# FastReport.Utils.CompilerException: (0,0): Error CS0006: Metadata file 'Microsoft.CSharp' could not be found

Tags: metadata, fastreport

I always get this error when i call report.Prepare() in dotnet framework 4.8 and vb
[image]

How do I solve this?